# jqGrid tableToGrid function

Tags: jqgrid

I couldnt find a simple example of how to use the tableToGrid function ( or atleast i couldnt get my sample to run). 
Can anyone help ? 
Here's my HTML test:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Content/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Content/Scripts/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Content/Scripts/jqGrid/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Content/Scripts/jqGrid/grid.base.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Content/Scripts/jqGrid/jqDnR.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<table id="table" class="classname">
<tr><td>bla</td><td>2nd td</td><td>3rd td</td></tr>
<tr><td>bla</td><td>2nd td</td><td>3rd td</td></tr>
<tr><td>bla</td><td>2nd td</td><td>3rd td</td></tr>
<tr><td>bla</td><td>2nd td</td><td>3rd td</td></tr>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
    //    debugger;
    //    tableToGrid('#classname', {});

    $(document).ready(function () { tableToGrid(".table"); });


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Update: after looking at the examples ( and changeing the '.' to '#' ) i added some elemnts to the table and it worked. Here's the revised HTML:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
<!--    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/Styles/jsTree/style.css" type="text/css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Content/Scripts/jsTree/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Content/Scripts/jsTree/jquery.hotkeys.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Content/Scripts/jsTree/jquery.jstree.js"></script>-->

    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Content/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Content/Scripts/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Content/Scripts/jqGrid/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Content/Scripts/jqGrid/grid.base.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Content/Scripts/jqGrid/jqDnR.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="button" id="button" /> 

<table id="table" class="classname" border="1">
<thead>
<tr><th>sdfsdf</th><th>sdfgfdgdf</th><th>sdgfdfsgdfg</th></tr></thead>
<tbody>
<tr><td>bla</td><td>2nd td</td><td>3rd td</td></tr>
<tr><td>bla</td><td>2nd td</td><td>3rd td</td></tr>
<tr><td>bla</td><td>2nd td</td><td>3rd td</td></tr>
<tr><td>bla</td><td>2nd td</td><td>3rd td</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">

   // $("#button").click(function () { tableToGrid("#table"); });
    //$("#button").click(function () { tableToGrid("#table"); });
    $(document).ready(function () { tableToGrid("#table"); });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, you need to reference the table using it's ID:

```
tableToGrid("#table")
```

For reference, there is a working demo of `tableToGrid` [here](http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html#), under `New in version 3.3` | `HTML Table to Grid`. You can look at their code on the web, and you can also download the demos and run them locally.

Comment: thank you ! i kept reaching the site you mentioned but i couldnt find where those examples were. Thanks alot :P